# Record Silverlight 4 MediaElement content

Tags: silverlight-4.0, streaming, video-capture, mediaelement

At the moment I'm working on a project. Which contains streaming from an IP camera to the Silverlight 4 MediaElement. The stream that goes through the MediaElement, needs to be cut when a button is clicked.

So is it possible to record MediaElement's content on demand? When that's done, write the recorded part of MediaElement to disk.
If it is possible, what's the most efficient way to do this?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, extract part of the entirely video, you can just use a program which has record screen function to [record silverlight video](http://www.streaming-video-recorder.com/record-silverlight-video.html) on demand. Then you just play the video and use it to start recording from desired beginning and finish recording at intended ending. Thus you will get demand content.